# How can I query data from 3+ tables connected that are connected with foreign keys?

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I have a [Search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDL2U.png) where users can search based on certain criteria. I cannot get the query right to display only one of the desired objects. Here is our database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Class
    (       
        cid int NOT NULL,
        classNum int,
        classDept varchar(20),
        PRIMARY KEY (cid)
    );

CREATE TABLE Book
    (
        bid int NOT NULL,
        cid int NOT NULL,
        title varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
        author varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        isbn varchar(13),
        price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (bid),
        FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Class (cid)
    );

CREATE TABLE Contact
    (
        contactID int NOT NULL,
        fname varchar(20),
        lname varchar(20),
        contactInfo varchar(90) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (contactID)
    );

CREATE TABLE Post
    (
        pid int NOT NULL,
        contactID int NOT NULL,
        bid int NOT NULL,
        postDate date,
        PRIMARY KEY (pid),
        FOREIGN KEY (contactID) references Contact(contactID),
        FOREIGN KEY (bid) references Book(bid)
    );
```

Here is the php code we are using to try to query based on criteria the user has entered.

```
$author = $_POST["author"];
     $title = $_POST["title"];
     $classNum = $_POST["number"];
     $classDept = $_POST["department"];
     $isbn = $_POST["isbn"];


     $query = "SELECT title, author, isbn, price, classNum, classDept, contactInfo
     FROM Book, Class, Contact, Post
     WHERE 
        Book.author='$author'
        OR Book.title='$title' 
        AND (SELECT Book.bid FROM Book, Contact WHERE Book.cid=Class.cid AND Contact.contactID=Post.ContactID AND Book.bid=Post.bid";
     $stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
     oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
```

What are we doing wrong? How can we get the proper search results to display?

Comment: Thanks for providing the create statements. Now you need to post the insert statements for sample data and show us the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your sample.  Firstly you mix `AND`s and `OR`s without parentheses which may lead to surprising results. Secondly you are missing the join clauses in the outer query, and thirdly your subquery does not have a matching closing bracket.

Here is a query which I believe is what you might be trying to accomplish.  Note I have used the ANSI joining syntax.  You can switch this to the "Oracle" style syntax and it will work exactly the same.  However, I recommend learning the ANSI way because this makes any outer joins you might need much easier to understand.

```
SELECT title, author, isbn, price, classNum, classDept, contactInfo
  FROM Book
  JOIN Class
    ON Class.cid = Book.cid
  JOIN Post
    ON Post.bid = Book.bid
  JOIN Contact
    ON Contact.contactID = Post.contactID
 WHERE Book.author = '$author'
    OR Book.title = '$title';
```

Finally, to get the author or title into the query, you should research query parameters.  I am not experienced with PHP, so I cannot advise how to proceed with this client.  It should be straight forward though.  As a short cut, you can concatenate the values directly into the query.  However this is not recommended for any serious real-world project as you will be vulnerable to [SQL-injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).